# Stub for formal parameter passed by reference in PHPSpec/Prophecy

Tags: php, phpspec

I have a method in PHP which looks like this:

```
<?php
class SomeClass
{
    public function isEntitledToDiscount(GuestModel $who, $onWhat, &$discountAmount = null)
    {
        $discountAmount = 10;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to stub `$discountAmount` in PHPSpec? Let's say I have a class I'm testing, and I've injected `$someService` via constructor. In my spec I use:

```
<?php
$someService->isEntitledToDiscount($guest, $ticket, $discountAmount)->willReturn(true);
```

which creates stub for method return value. How can I do this with the `$discountAmount` formal parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method shouldn't modify its arguments (shouldn't have side effects). Especially a getter-type method. **You should probably rethink your design.**

Your problem is actually related to prohpecy, so you might want to read its docs: https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy

Prophecy (and PhpSpac) **make some things hard**. In most cases it means that **you're trying to take a wrong turn with your design**.

You could try the following, but I don't think you'll get a reference to your variable:

```php
$someService->isEntitledToDiscount($guest, $ticket, $discountAmount)
    ->will(function ($arguments) {
        // do your evil
    });
```

Recommended read: [Command Query Separation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html).

Comment: How can this be an answer to OP's question?